# Gmail API server to server application (Bad Request error)

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api, service-accounts

I'm following this tutorial [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount). I am trying to connect to the Gmail API using a service account.

The code I end up with looks like this:

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from httplib2 import Http
from apiclient.discovery import build
import json

scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('******.json', scopes)

http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())
service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=http_auth)
request = service.users().messages().list(userId='me')
response = request.execute()

print json.dumps(response, sort_keys=True, indent=2)
```

However, when I run this code, I get the following error:

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError:https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?alt=json returned "Bad Request">

Can someone help me understand where this error is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Think of a service account as a dummy user.  It has a Google Drive account a google calendar account.  What it doesn't to my knowlage is have a Gmail account.

Normally when you request data using a service account you have to grant the service account access to that data manually.  In the case of google drive you can share a folder with the service account enabling it to access google drive.  (you can also upload to its drive account but that's out of scope for this question)

There is no way to grant another user access to your Gmail account so there is no way to use a service account with a normal user Gmail account.

Note: If this is Not a normal user Gmail account and is in fact one based on google domains then you can grant the service account access to all the emails of the other users on the domain via the admin section.

Other wise you need to look into using Oauth2 to access gmail.